# (Crazy idea) Line integral and the generalization of the $x$-axis

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

I've been thinking about the mathematical motivation of the definition of line integrals and a crazy idea came to my mind.

First of all, let's begin with the definition of integral line of a function:

> If $f$ is defined on a smooth curve $\gamma:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$, then the **line integral of $f$ along $\gamma$** is
>
> $$\int_{\gamma}f(x,y)ds=\int_a^bf(\gamma(t))|\gamma'(t)|dt$$

For me this definition is simply saying that the line integration is the one where the function is being integrate over a curve instead of a $x$-axis:

[image]

Note the $|\gamma'(t)|$ is the correction of the lengths of the partitions of the curves (the partitions are in the curve instead of the $x$-axis).

Am I right?

Comment: It sounds like you want to define a Riemann-style integral of $f$ along $\gamma$ using partitions of the range of $\gamma$; rather than the given definition of the line integral, which operates on the domain of $\gamma$, namely $[a,b]$. Let's call the new definition the "user42912 integral". Then you really want to know: (1) Is the user42912 integral well-defined? (2) Does it equal the line integral when both are defined? (3) Is the user42912 integral superior is any way? I suspect that (1) Yes (2) Yes and (3) Yes, because it will generalize better to non-smooth curves. Is that a good framing?

Comment: @ChrisCulter good points. I didn't realized the domains are different. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but do you mean something like this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3KGBkbYunXY

Comment: @HansLundmark Thank you very much, this video helped me a lot.